# Bibliography and listoffigures postion

Tags: table-of-contents, bibliographies, page-breaking

Whatever I try, I cannot "force" listoffigures and bibliography to be rendered in wanted position. They allways end up on next page, even if there is enough space in previous (wanted) page.

CODE:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}

\chapter{Appendix}
\section{List of figures}
\renewcommand*\listfigurename{}  % remove title
\listoffigures{}

\chapter{Bibliography}
\renewcommand\bibname{}   % remove title
\begin{thebibliography}{99}
```

RESULT:

> Chapter 6
>
> APPENDIX
>
> 6.1 List of figures
>
> *
>
> *
>
> *
>
> *
>
> *
>
> (ACTUAL LIST)

(new page)

> Chapter 7
>
> Bibliography
>
> *
>
> *
>
> *
>
> *
>
> *
>
> (ACTUAL BIBLIOGRAPHY)

WANTED RESULT:

> Chapter 6
>
> APPENDIX
>
> 6.1 List of figures
>
> (ACTUAL LIST)

(new page)

> Chapter 7
>
> Bibliography
>
> (ACTUAL BIBLIOGRAPHY)

I hope you get the picture, what am I trying to say (those asterisks represent blank spaces).

Comment: Im using \documentclass[a4paper, 12pt]{book}. And I know that \chapter begins on a new page, that is not the problem for me.

Comment: Actually it *is*, as, e.g., the `thebibliography` environment starts a new chapter in the `book` class (with your redefinition of `\bibname`, a chapter without name, but a chapter nevertheless).

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. But is there anyway to avoid this ? Can you somehow make chapters not starting on a new page? (just for the last part ofcourse)

Comment: @N10 To respond to users other than the post author, you need to prepend an `@` sign plus the username like I did now. It should be possible to come up with a solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you want to change the List of Figures and the Bibliography, which both are unnumbered chapters in the `book` class, to a numbered section resp. a numbered chapter. One way to do so is to use the `etoolbox` package to selectively change the definition of `\listoffigures` and `thebibliography`.

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{etoolbox}

\makeatletter

\patchcmd{\listoffigures}{%
  \chapter*{\listfigurename}\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename }{\MakeUppercase\listfigurename}%
}{
  \section{\listfigurename}%
}{}{}
\patchcmd{\thebibliography}{%
  \chapter*{\bibname}\@mkboth{\MakeUppercase\bibname }{\MakeUppercase\bibname}%
}{
  \chapter{\bibname}%
}{}{}

\makeatother

\begin{document}

\chapter{foo}

\begin{figure}
\centering
\rule{1cm}{1cm}% placeholder for graphic
\caption{A figure}
\end{figure}

\chapter{Appendix}

\listoffigures

\begin{thebibliography}{99}
\bibitem{A01} A bibitem.
\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```